# ReSharper autocompletion bug? with lambda scratch arguments

Tags: c#, lambda, autocomplete, resharper, resharper-9.2

I'm using ReSharper 9.2. Example code:

```
class Foo
{
   private int _someField;
   private int _someOtherField;

   public Foo()
   {
      Action<int, int> a = (_, __) => { };
   }
}
```

As soon as I type type the ',' after the '_', R# decides I must *really* mean `_someField`, and *automatically inserts it*. I have all three options (Symbol completion, Smart completion, and Import completion) unchecked under Options > Environment > IntelliSense > "Automatically complete single item with". But I suspect this feature is not the cause of the bug because there are 2 fields that begin with `_`, so there should be more than a single item in the suggestion list.

It also isn't due to `_` being treated as a magic character; if I name the fields `xSomeField` and `xSomeOtherField` and call the scratch variable `x`, I get the same thing.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I usually handle this by hitting escape when the selection window comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally I discovered workarounds on my own almost immediately after posting the question. Each is a compromise that means losing a bit of functionality elsewhere, so pick your poison:

1. *Options > Environment > IntelliSense > Autopopup > C#*: Set *both* "Where value is expected" *and* "Letters and digits" to "Display but do not preselect"
2. *Options > Environment > IntelliSense > Completing Characters > C# > Do not complete on*: Add ',' to the list

The bug seems to be that R# doesn't realize that, in this context, you are actually naming a new variable and instead applies its "where value is expected" behavior.